# Expo Deep linking on iOS is not working (because of Google sign-in?)

Tags: ios, expo, google-signin

Deep linking is not working. This is how the `info.plist` on iOS is configured for Google sign-in.

```
    ...
    <key>GIDClientID</key>
    <string>[secret].apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.[secret]</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I remove this part, deep linking works fine, why is that?
Am I doing something wrong?